# PyQt5 Items of my Gui does not appear when I use the loop "while" to check if a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm coding a program that converts a currency into the other currency you choosed from the ListBox.

I'm having trouble with this program. If I use the loop while to check, items of my Gui does not appear to me.

Here are my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By as by
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys as key
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from interface import *
import time
import sys

class CurrencyConverter(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Interface()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.ui.amountbox.setVisible(1)
        self.stepOne()

    def stepOne(self):
        while True:
            if self.ui.Amount.isChecked():
                self.ui.amountbox.setVisible(0)
            else:
                self.ui.amountbox.setVisible(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = CurrencyConverter()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: That's because you should *not* use a loop, but connect the checkbox's [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) to a function that will eventually do whatever you need. Do some research on how signals and slot work, so that you could better understand how Qt generally works.

Comment: I wrote some code under __init__, they were checking if CheckBox is open, but they didn't work.

Comment: BugraPakir what musicamante is saying is you cannot use while loops in PyQt unless done in a thread. When you use the while loop you block the eventloop from refreshing the GUI elements until that while loop is complete. In your case it never completes because you are in the loop forever.

Comment: You should instead use a signal/slot implementation where instead of `self.stepOne()` you should use `self.ui.Amount.toggled.connect(self.stepOne)`

Comment: in this case the checkbox will emit a signal called "toggle" when the checkbox is toggled and it will connect that signal to self.stepOne() which in this case is the slot.

Comment: well, is there any way to do what i want to do by not using while loop? what i wanna do is i want to check if the checkbox is checked or not, if it's checked, the textbox being hide is going to show itself, but if it's not, it should continue to be hide.

Comment: @BugraPakir You don't wanna check if the checkbox is checked or not, you'll want to have a function called when the checkbox state *changes* (and eventually do something using the current state at the time that the function is called). That's what the `toggled` signal does, and what the function connected to that signal will do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of what is suggested in the comments.

You connect with the buttons `toggled` signal and use your `setOne` method as the slot.  The signal is emited with a boolean value as an argument indicating the checkstate which you can then use to conditionally perform some action.  The signal is automatically emitted every time the state of the button is changed, so no while loops are necessary.

```
...

class CurrencyConverter(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        ...
 
        self.ui.amount.toggled.connect(self.stepOne)  # signal connection

    def setOne(self, ischecked):   # slot method
        if ischecked:    
            self.ui.amountbox.setVisible(0)
        else:
            self.ui.amountbox.setVisible(1)
```

Comment: It works, thank you sir. I have a question; what does the parameter of the setOne "ischecked" exactly do?

Comment: where can i contact with you on? if you have a discord, or instagram, can we contact with each other? i just started learning PyQt5, i want to ask you the questions i dont know about PyQt5

Comment: @bugrapakir ischecked is just a boolean... It's either true or false.  If the the variable is True, then the button is checked, if it is false it means it isn't checked